# Flutter android app stuck in white screen after I download from playstore

Tags: flutter, screen

I have published an app on the play store and they working fine on All devices. I have Add Admob on the app and Update My app on play store they Stuck in the gray screen, I have tried so many codes to fix. But issue but That not fix, Finally, I have to Publish my Old Code that but now they also not working and they stuck, in Gray Screen and I restore my all testing device.

I have a test app on the real device before Uploading on the alpha testing app is working fine, but  after uploading on alpha testing they show a gray screen

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it worked in release mode but with the app bundle in the play store it freezed on a white screen. There is an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65334) on github, try to downgrade the gradle version in `android/build.gradle` to

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1`

It worked for my app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Riccardo,  you're a life saver. Although, I did change the version to ```com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.3``` as it was conflicting with Gradle distributions link ```6.1.1``` from  ```gradle.properties```.

Answer (score 0):

before the publish app on playstore first test it in real device, you can also try it on alpha or beta test.

Comment: Yes I have a test app on the real device, they Woking but  after uploading on alpha testing they show a gray screen

Comment: tested app is released mode?

Comment: you have check all permission in menifest.xml file, may be internet permission is not there,

Comment: I now have the same issue. It works fine locally when testing with --release mode on my device, but not when installing from the Google Play store. Last release included Local Notifications only, so we're troubleshooting the permissions and setup configuration again. Any other suggestions? Thanks