# white screen crash/hang at startup in my production release flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle

hope you all healthy. little problem aroused in my flutter app. i have released flutter apk on play store. it was working fine. after some change i published updated version of my app. now on **some users'** phone app stuck/hang at startup showing only white screen. **it works fine on debug and fat releasae apk's**. I tried most upvoted suggestion/issue but no success:

1. [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65334)
2. [flutter app stuck on white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336551/flutter-android-app-stuck-in-white-screen-after-i-download-from-playstore)

my `android/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tm.com.getirtm"
        minSdkVersion 21 //
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" //
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' //
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' //
}
```

my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="smth.com.example">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="SomeApp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:fullBackupOnly="false">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

my `pubcpec.yaml` file:

```
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 3.1.8+32

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.5 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  back_button_interceptor: ^2.0.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  conditional_builder: ^1.0.2
  cupertino_icons: any
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  device_info: ^1.0.0
  dio: ^3.0.10
  equatable: ^1.2.6
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  flare_splash_screen: ^3.0.1
  flutter_images_slider: ^0.0.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.7
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  launch_review: ^2.0.0
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^1.2.1
  package_info: ^0.4.3+4
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  photo_view: ^0.10.3
  provider: ^4.0.0
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.4
  sentry_flutter: ^4.0.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  sqflite: ^1.3.0+1
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  rxdart: ^0.25.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1

flutter_icons:
  ios: true
  android: true
  image_path_ios: "assets/images/launcher/app_icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/images/android_launcher/app_icon.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec
# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/logo.flr
    - assets/images/logo.png
    - assets/images/g.flr
    - assets/images/empty.png
    - assets/images/logo_text.png
    - assets/images/revenue.png
    - assets/images/down.png
    - assets/images/up.png
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.
  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

my `flutter doctor`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.746], locale en-US)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.      
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update this block:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Not sure if it's build-tools update; I'd rather assume it lacks R8 configuration rules.

Comment: i have read [this article](https://medium.com/@swav.kulinski/flutter-and-android-obfuscation-8768ac544421) after your answer. what is R8 and minifyEnabled? ALso do i need `proguard files`?

Comment: okay but purpose of my question is to clarify the line you added. what is purpose of that line?

Comment: bro while trying to build apk it is giving this error: `Removing unused resources requires unused code shrinking to be turned on`. i googled it. it says i should set `minifyEnabled` to **true**. why is that?